# Applying XGBOOST with large data set

Tags: xgboost, r-bigmemory, bigdata

I have a large dataset with size approximately 5.3 GB and i have stored data using bigmemory() in R. Please let me know how to apply XGBOOST to this kind of data??

Answer (score 3):

There currently is no support for this with `xgboost`.  You could file an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues) with respect to the R package.

Otherwise, you could attempt to have it read from a file of your data.  The docs say you can point to a local data file.  Not sure about format restrictions or how it will be handled in RAM but something to explore.